# Unable to dequeue a cell error while connected to a Prototype Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am stuck on what I thought would be a simple task.
I have a `UITableView` that is set to Prototype Cell.

I have added some cell for specific use in the "case".

I am getting the error "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier `TankStartCell` - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard" however, the scene is set up as a Prototype Cell.

The cell in question does have the "StartTankCell" in the identifier.

The Location cell works.

I have tried adding: 
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "StartTankCell")
but no go.
I have tried making the class a `UIViewController` and adding `UITableViewDelegate`, but no go.

```objc
private let NumberOfSections: Int               = 6
private let NumberOfRowsInSection0: Int         = 1
private let NumberOfRowsInSection1: Int         = 4
private let NumberOfRowsInSection2: Int         = 5
private let NumberOfRowsInSection3: Int         = 6
private let NumberOfRowsInSection4: Int         = 8
private let NumberOfRowsInSection5: Int         = 1



//  Section 0 Cells
private let DiveLocationIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

//  Section 1 Cells
private let DiveStartingPressureIndex: NSIndexPath      = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)
private let DiveEndingPressureIndex: NSIndexPath        = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)
private let DiveTempPickerIndexAir: NSIndexPath         = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 1)
private let DiveTempPickerIndexWater: NSIndexPath       = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 1)

//  Section 2 Cells
private let DiveWaterIndex: NSIndexPath                 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 2)
private let DiveWeatherIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2)
private let DiveSurfaceIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 2)
private let DiveCurrentsIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 2)
private let DiveVisibilityIndex: NSIndexPath            = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 2)

//  Section 3 Cells
private let DiveEntryTypeIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3)
private let DiveWeightIndex: NSIndexPath                = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 3)
private let DiveDiveSuitIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 3)
private let DiveCircuitIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 3)
private let DiveAirTypeIndex: NSIndexPath               = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 3)
private let DiveDiveTypeIndex: NSIndexPath              = NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 3)


// Section 4 Cells
private let DiveMasterTitleIndex: NSIndexPath           = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 4)
private let DiveMasterIndex: NSIndexPath                = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 4)
private let DiveCenterTitleIndex: NSIndexPath           = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 4)
private let DiveCenterIndex: NSIndexPath                = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 4)
private let DiveBoatTitleIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 4)
private let DiveBoatIndex: NSIndexPath                  = NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 4)
private let DiveTripTitleIndex: NSIndexPath             = NSIndexPath(forRow: 6, inSection: 4)
private let DiveTripIndex: NSIndexPath                  = NSIndexPath(forRow: 7, inSection: 4)



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    switch indexPath
    {

    // Section 0
    case DiveLocationIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.LocationCell)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Location".localized
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(format: "%f, %f", self.latitude, self.longitude)




    // Section 1
    case DiveStartingPressureIndex:
        let cell : DiveStartTankPressureTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TankStartCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DiveStartTankPressureTableViewCell

        cell.lbl_Start_Pressure.text = Strings.StartingPressure.localized
        cell.txtStartPressure_Symbol.placeholder = "PSI / Bar"
        cell.txtStartPressure.text = userDefault.objectForKey("startPressure") as? String
        cell.txtStartPressure_Symbol.text =  userDefault.objectForKey("symbol_startPressure") as? String
        userDefault.synchronize()
        return cell
```

My `DiveStartTankPressureTableViewCell` looks like this:

```objc
class DiveStartTankPressureTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_Start_Pressure: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtStartPressure: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtStartPressure_Symbol: UITextField!

    private(set) var startingTank : String?
    private(set) var startingTankSymbol : String?

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UITableVieCell Methods

    //
    //  Called when we are initialized from a storyboard or nib file.
    //
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    //
    //  The item has been selected in the table.
    //
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate Method Implementation

    //
    //  We are called when the user is done editing.
    //
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
    {
        startingTank = txtStartPressure.text
        startingTankSymbol = txtStartPressure_Symbol.text
        itemToParse()
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(startingTank, forKey: "startingTank")
        aCoder.encodeObject(startingTankSymbol, forKey: "startingTankSymbol")
    }

    func itemToParse () {

        let updateDiveQuery = PFQuery(className: "divelog")
        updateDiveQuery.whereKey("uuid", equalTo: diveUUID)
        updateDiveQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let updateDiveObject = objects {

                    updateDiveObject["startingTank"]        = self.startingTank
                    updateDiveObject["startingTankSymbol"]      = self.startingTankSymbol

                    updateDiveObject.pinInBackground()
                    updateDiveObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {(done:Bool, error:NSError?) in

                        if done {
                            print ("ParseData UPDATED data saved")

                        } else {
                            updateDiveObject.saveEventually()
                        }
                    }

                    if PFUser.currentUser()!.username == nil {
                        updateDiveObject["username"] = "Not Signed in"
                    } else {
                        updateDiveObject["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
                    }
                    updateDiveObject.saveEventually()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas where to look?

EDIT, adding a screenshot of my Storyboard

[image]

Interesting update. I tried "Plain" and not "Group" and the error changed to the below:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10623e278) to 'RLA_DiveLog.DiveStartTankPressureTableViewCell' (0x1022fb330).
```

Comment: Are the other prototype cells working?  If so then double check your cell identifier spelling & case carefully

Comment: Not sure as this is first on the list. The LocationCell works, but is a different format. However, it is still a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. That is what baffles me. I had checked spelling many times.

Comment: Just a short notice: You are using the Parse framework. Are you aware that their service is shutting down after Jan 2017? Unless you've deployed Parse server to your backend, your app is going to be obsolete by then :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I am using Back4App.com as they have the same parse set up as Parse.com does.  This allows me to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to set your `tableViews` `TankStartCell` `identifier` using `Attribute inspector` by selecting prototype cell see image below ..

[image]

Hope this helps ..

Comment: See above edit. I added a screen shot.  The identifier is set up.  That is why I am so baffled.

Comment: @DavidSanford something is missing there may be a duplication of identifier or ..just apply hard

Comment: Not sure I follow "hard"

Comment: have you set the class for the `UITableViewController` to your class in that scene or **have you set the relevant class to `cell`** ?

Comment: Or just try cleaning the build folder press `shift+command+option+k` key then a window prompt choose `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your cell is the right type as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very odd one indeed.

After some research, it seems that Xcode was utilizing two different Storyboards.  When I would click on Main.Storyboard and update this storyboard, it had no effect as my ViewController was using Main.Storyboard(Base).

No idea how this came to be, but it is clearly an Xcode 8 issue.

Hope this helps others with this odd issue.